# Remove 'Payment fee' in totals

Tags: magento-1.9, totals

Does anybody know where 'Payment fee' is coming from in totals? See image below. I want to get rit of it.

[image]

Comment: You have using any third party extension which add the payment free option

Comment: its really strange its not from PostNL and not from Docdata. How can i find out where its come from? I looked everywhere in backend...